# How to get a non-negative output in lstm keras

Tags: keras, lstm, data-science

I am doing a prediction for time series data using lstm keras. The train does not contain any negative numbers.

The issue is, when the training error decreases to a certain level, the outputted prediction sometimes is negative, which does not make sense in my application.

Below is my RNN:

```python
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,stateful=False,activation='relu', input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', W_constraint=nonneg()))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer= 'adam')     
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, validation_split = 0.20, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

This happens mainly when the train data has lot of zeros. How can i prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Your output layer has `activation='linear'`, which means you are using a normal linear function for your output and values can range from -∞ to +∞.

[image]

If you only have two possible outputs, try using a sigmoid function S(x) = 1/(1+e^-x). These values only range from 0 to 1.

[image: Sigmoid Function]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But with activation as sigmoid my predictions results not accurate as before, i found an option of using W_constraint=nonneg() but it is not working. Do we have any similar things that avoids getting negative outputs.

Comment: are you doing some sort of classification? how many classes are there?

Comment: Hi J.Panek, I am forecasting the number of enrollment of students in a school. This time series is 70% of '0' and only some dates have a number, which in this case is a count (3 students enrolled, 12 students enrolled...). Maybe Alok is facing a similar scenario